# Global login but still have customer seperated

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, websites

I have 1 magento instance with 2 different websites set up within it. The websites are /retail and /trade

Within the header I have a link to a login page. The issue I have is that if a trade user was to try and login on the /retail site then magento would say the login is invalid because the customer accounts are not shared.

Therefore my question is this, is it possible to have a global login page and then you customer to be redirected to the correct website based on their account?

Comment: did you have check Magenrto Customer sharing setting at `admin>System>Configuration>Customer>Account Sharing Options>Share Customer Accounts =Global.`

Comment: I dont really want to that option to be global as then retail customers will be able to login into the trade website. Ideally I would like a global login but to keep the customer accounts different

Comment: Also if I enable global for account sharing then although a trade user can login using the /retail site if they go to /trade then they are not logged in